# How to check if option contains empty char?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist with list of some values from database.

```
<asp:DropDownList Runat="server" ID="cmbSalut" data-bind="value: drSalut"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Depending on what kind of record are opened, I am selecting its proper value in dropdown, and in case if there are nothing, I am selecting default value.

I use this to select default value:

```
$('select[Id="cmbSalut"] > option:contains("")').prop('selected', true);
```

It works fine until one issue appeared. It works because my datatable for dropdown contains record with "" value (empty value), but if I change it to " " (or more white spaces), this select not working anymore (it will be ignoret and last one value will be selected).

So my question is, how can I select option which value is empty or white space by using jquery (what should I change in my existing select)?

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT:**
Fixed it.
Instead of contains use, I needed to write this:

```
('select[Id="cmbSalut"]').find('option[text=""]').prop('selected', true);
```

Worked out as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can use `.filter()` and return true if option has empty value. make use of `.trim()` to handle any empty space.

```
$('select[Id="cmbSalut"] > option').filter(function(){
   return ""==$(this).val().trim();
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work out. But there were difference. Right now, unstead of empty value, I am getting last one from data base. With your example, I got first one.

Comment: can you share me the view of select box after fetching database values? If possible, can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statment.

Comment: Managed to deal with it :D Actually, contains use was a really bad idea. Changed it to ('select[Id="cmbSalut"]').find('option[text=""]').prop('selected', true); and its worked out as it needed.